# Variable number of fields in Django URL

Tags: django, django-urls

I'd like a URL of the form:

```
... field1/eq/value1/field2/gt/value2/ ...
```

Where I want to filter the contents of the page in the view function based on an arbitrary number of fields (the names of which are not known in advance).

I've tried:

```
(r'^((?P<field>\w+)/(?P<op>[a-z]+)/(?P<value>\w+)/)*$', my_view)
```

But the keyword arguments are filled with the last set of three field/op/value to occur in the URL.

Is there any way that I could populate a list or dictionary based on a variable number of URl fields like this?

Or should I be doing this some completely different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do this.

Use the query string.  `?field,eq,value&field,gt,value` will work out much better.